# Changing CSS property of the attribute "draggable"

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

Is it possible to change the CSS property of the attribute "draggable"

```
draggable="true"
```

Is it possible to change the default style given to the element by HTML??...  When dragging, the element is transparent until it gets dropped, but I want it to be fully visible when being dragged. I was hoping to do this WITHOUT jquery UI.

Comment: Check what class is added to helper element. Then style it the way you want. E.g. `.draggable .helper {opacity: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage()
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    
    if (ev.target.className == "card-content") { 
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
}
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
   <div class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
     Drag Me
   </div>
</body>
```